# jquery accordion prevent bubbling / allow default link action

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, event-bubbling

I have an accordion setup as so:

```
 $('.shortheadline').accordion({ active: false, header: '.headline',  autoHeight: false, animated: 'slowslide', changestart: function(event, ui) { $('.brief').css('min-height','0') }, change: function(event, ui) {  $('.brief:visible').css('min-height','80px'); $('.headline').blur(); } });
```

I want the click to only register on the .headline div, not the link inside.  The link should take you to the article page.

```
   <div class="shortheadline"> 
        <div class="entry">
            <div class="headline">
                <div class="timestamp">11:34 AM</div>
                <div class="title"><a href="http://beta.macobserver.com/tmo/article/jeff_gamet_shares_iphone_tips_and_tricks_on_macjury/">Jeff Gamet Shares iPhone Tips and Tricks on MacJury</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="brief">
                <div class="teaser_image"> <img src="/imgs/cache/imgs/teaser_images/20090708macjury_new-0x80.png" width="80" height="80"  id="teas_48236" alt="macJuryJeff Gamet Shares iPhone Tips and Tricks on MacJury" /></div>
                <div class="teaser"><p><em>The Mac Observer's</em> Jeff Gamet joined <em>MacJury</em> host Chuck Joiner to talk about Apple's iPhone OS 3.0, the iPhone 3GS, and to share some iPhone tips and tricks, too.</p> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- more entries -->
    </div>
```

Is there a way to prevent event bubbling so the accordion only triggers on clicking a div?
Or is there a way to allow the link's default action to continue?

I've tried:

```
$("a").click(function(){ window.location=this.href;  });
```

Which does make the link function, but it doesn't let the user open the link in a new tab/window.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
$("a").click(function(event){ event.stopPropagation(); });
```

The click function is passed an 'event' object. By calling the 'stopPropagation' method of the event object, you can prevent bubbling.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  I looked up stopPropagation and it was just what I was looking for.  I didn't even need the window.location part.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this alternative syntax which worked for me;

```
$("a").bind("click", function(e) {e.stopPropagation();});
```