# How to cancel change event for accordion controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    change: function (event, ui) {
        alert('event have to be changed')
    },
    changestart: function (event, ui) {
       return false;
    }
});
```

Is it possible to cancel the change event?

Comment: this cancel event but  action still working

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure about change but for other events in jqueryui returning false cancels the event.

Comment: This works because return false is equivalent to calling `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 3):

stopPropagation() is the key to stopping a jQueryUI action from processing, but it must be interrupted BEFORE the changestart event.  For example, when the header item is actually clicked.

If this is a header/content pair in your accordion:

```
<h3 class='noexpand'>This is a dummy header</h3>
<div>This is dummy content</div>
```

Then this will prevent the accordion from expanding the div when the header is clicked:

```
$("h3.noexpand").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

See [jquery accordion prevent bubbling / allow default link action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135466/jquery-accordion-prevent-bubbling-allow-default-link-action).

Answer (score 2):

As Martin said you can return false. See a code sample below.

```
...
eventname: function( event, ui ) {
    // Add your code here
    ...

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagate();
```

Comment: `stopPropagation()`, not "stopPropogate()"

Answer (score 0):

Returning false does nothing, to cancel an event in jQueryUI you need to call preventDefault() on the event.

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    changestart: function (event, ui) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This should work with all event methods, including autocomplete. Handy if you wish to include a few custom options in your autocomplete menu that you want someone to select but don't actually want to add to the input it is tied to. :)

Comment: "These handlers, therefore, may prevent the delegated handler from triggering by calling event.stopPropagation() or returning false." - http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: This actually doesn't work.  It was my first thought too.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is calling:

```
function onChange(e, ui) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Returning `false` at the end of the function has the same affect because it's the equivalent of making those two function calls.