# Can I cancel all jquery events attached to child divs of a parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent div called "wrapper", which contains several children divs, each with some jquery attached to them. All the jquery code is contained within the div. Is there a way to cancel all the jquery within `#wrapper`?

To illustrate:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sub1"></div>
  <div id="sub2"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#sub1").click(function () {
      //do something
    });
    $("#sub2").click(function () {
      //do something
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323772/how-to-cancel-event-for-jquery-ui-controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$('#wrapper').children().unbind();

Remove event handler on child elements

Comment: Really? `.children` finds all the parent's children, just like that?

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4yjohnz7/3/)

Try this

Html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    Check
  <div id="sub1" class='sub_click'>Test1</div>
  <div id="sub2" class='sub_click'>Test2</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$("#wrapper").click(function () {
      //do something
        $(this).children(".sub_click").unbind();
    });

    $("#sub1").click(function () {
      //do something
        alert("a");
        return false;
    });
    $("#sub2").click(function () {
      //do something
        alert("b");
        return false;
    });
```