# jQuery UI Accordion (non-accordioning level)

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a jQuery accordion menu and I know at some point I am going to want to have one of the levels not expand out (so it will be clickable instead of opening up the accordion) and I can't seem to figure it out or find documentation on how to do it.

Take a look at the second level of my sample code. I tried leaving it empty, I tried an open and close div tag and I also tried what you see below an open and close UL tag and each one causes the menu to accordion at that level leaving a big blank spot. Any suggestions?

```
<script>
$.ui.accordion.animations.superbounce = function(options) {
    this.slide(options, {
            autoHeight: false,
            duration: options.down ? 2000 : 500,
            duration: options.up ? 2000 : 500
    });

}; 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({animated: 'superbounce'});
    });
});

</script>
<div id="accordion">
<h3><a href="#">Masters Of Arts</a></h3>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Business Psychology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Criminology and Justice Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Educational Leadership</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Executive Coaching</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Health and Wellness Psychology</a></li>
    </ul>

<h3><a href="#">Masters Of Arts</a></h3>

<ul></ul>

<h3><a href="#">Doctor of Philosophy</a></h3>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Business Psychology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Criminology and Justice Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Educational Leadership</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Executive Coaching</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Health and Wellness Psychology</a></li>
    </ul>

<h3><a href="#">Doctor of Psychology</a></h3>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Business Psychology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Criminology and Justice Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Educational Leadership</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Executive Coaching</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Health and Wellness Psychology</a></li>
    </ul>

<h3><a href="#">Masters Of Arts 2</a></h3>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Business Psychology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Criminology and Justice Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Educational Leadership</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Executive Coaching</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Health and Wellness Psychology</a></li>
    </ul>

<h3><a href="#">Masters Of Arts 3</a></h3>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Business Psychology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Criminology and Justice Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Educational Leadership</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Executive Coaching</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Health and Wellness Psychology</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Where's the jQuery code?

Comment: I included it, but its not really relevant as it is just there to initialize the accordion. But if it helps, its there now.

Comment: Borderline duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135466/jquery-accordion-prevent-bubbling-allow-default-link-action  (The goal in that question is different, but it still addresses keeping an accordion pane from opening when a link is clicked in the header.)

Answer (score 0):

What if you were to add a class to the list items that you want to have open a link:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a class="link" href="yourlink.html">Masters Of Arts</a></h3>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Then, with jQuery you can stop the link from opening the accordion:

```
$(".link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Just FYI, I haven't actually tested this out, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work. I don't believe preventDefault works because you are preventing the <a> tag from linking which is the default instead of preventing the accordion from expanding.

Comment: preventDefault() prevents the normal browser action for the item.  stopPropagation(), on the other hand, prevents further jQuery events for the item, and will stop the accordion from expanding.

Answer (score 0):

Between @Dave and @Ryan I arrived at the answer. @Ryan had the right idea

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a class="link" href="yourlink.html">Masters Of Arts</a></h3>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

with @Dave adding the missing ingredient

```
$(".link").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
}
```

All I needed to do was use stopPropagation instead of preventDefault and that did the trick, thanks guys.